# python recursive function loops infinitely

Tags: python, function, recursion

While trying to understand how recursion works in Python, I wrote the below function which searches a list for a given value. The idea is to sort the list then find the middle index within the *i*th and *j*th elements and comparing with the search value.
The problem is that it goes into an infinite loop. I have run the statements step by step and the required result obtains. Can someone point out where I got it wrong?

```
def search(lst, v):
    if not('i' in locals()) and not('j' in locals()):
        i = 0
        j = len(lst)
        
        # sort 
        lst.sort()
        
    midindex = i + int((j - i)/2)
    
    if lst[midindex] > v:
        j = midindex-1       
        return search(lst, v)
    elif lst[midindex] < v:
        i = midindex+1
        return search(lst, v)
    else:
        return midindex
```

Comment: are `search` and `bsearch` supposed to be the same function?

Comment: you're updating `i` and `j` but they are not being passed into function call?

Comment: What is `if not('i' in locals()) and not('j' in locals())` supposed to be doing? Those local variables are never going to exist at that point in the function.

Comment: `if` will always be True because each function call has its own name scope. You have to pass the values to actually check them

Comment: It would be so easy to just step through the code with a debugger and see what happens. You would not have needed to ask this question if you had done that. Linked reference to a working solution with recursion; passing the range indices as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that `locals` is, well, *local* to the function you're using it in. Each time you call the function (recursively or otherwise) a new variable namespace is created, so `locals` will always be empty. See for example:

```
def foo():
    x = 1
    print("foo locals:", locals())
    bar()

def bar():
    y = 2
    print("bar locals:", locals())

foo()
```

The output of which will be:

```
foo locals: {'x': 1}
bar locals: {'y': 2}
```

You need to pass any variables you want to use across function calls, like `i` and `j` as arguments:

```
def bsearch(search_list, value, i, j):
    ...
```

Comment: I was trying to make it a simpler form with only two arguments.